# Power Bi : sync slicers in 2 reports stored in the same workspace

Tags: powerbi, synchronization, slicers

I'd like to split a big report Power Bi in several reports stored in the same workspace and published in a Power Bi App.

Why splitting ?
The report display a lot of indicators.
The structure is "heavy" : a lot of tables and a lot of measures.

I hope that by having lighter reports, it will be easier to maintain and evolve.

But the different pages have a group of common slicers.
So that, when the user select a value in one of these slicers, all the indicators in the different pages are filtered on this value.

And I want to keep this functionality.
But this option doesn't exist natively in Power Bi Service : sync slicers in 2 reports

I search on Google, Stackoverflow, ChatGPT and Bing, and i don't find an alternative way.

Has anyone ever succeeded in transmitting the value of a filter made by one user to another Power Bi report?

These reports can be used by several people at the same time.